# Django - choose Choice value depending on view loaded

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a (forms.form) class where I have choices. I wish to decide whenever I load view_1, that the choice for that view is choice_A, and then when I load view_2, that the choice for that view is choice_B. So depending on the view loaded the choice value changes accordingly.

**Class for CreateGameForm(forms.form)**

```
class CreateGame(forms.Form):
    game_choices = ([
            ('choice_A', 'choice_A'),
            ('choice_B', 'choice_B')
             ])            

    game = forms.ChoiceField(choices=game_choices , required=True)
```

I have tried to make it work with changing the initial value by adding one to the game, and then in def **init** adding it together with a function that changes the initial value when the view/URL_pattern changes, but without much luck.

Any ideas?

**Using initial methodology**

```
class CreateGame(forms.Form):
    game_choices = ([
            ('choice_A', 'choice_A'),
            ('choice_B', 'choice_B')
             ])            

    game = forms.ChoiceField(choices=game_choices , required=True, initial="choice_A")
```

**My createView**

```
class CreateGameA(CreateView):
    template_name = 'otree/gameA.html'
    url_pattern = r"^create_game/gameA/"

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['game'] = 'gameA'
        return initial
```

**Edit**

Make sure to have FormMixin or use CreateView, otherwise you cannot use get_initial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using CreateView for your views, you can override get_initial() in each view.

```
class GameAView(CreateView):
     ...

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['game'] = 'choice_A'
        return initial


class GameBView(CreateView):
     ...

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['game'] = 'choice_B'
        return initial
```

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for. I've tried to replicate your method, but unfortunately without success. 

When I add initial to the ChoiceField. What should the initial be equal to? The game_choices? I will update my question with what I just tried.

Comment: Took some time but I figured out the right context that was needed in my program. You're answer is great and lead me in the right direction, thank you.